# Syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: shell

When I use below code in SSH terminal for CentOS it works fine:

```
paste <(printf "%s\n" "TOP")
```

But if I place the same line code in a shell script (test.sh) and run shell script from terminal, it throws error as this

```
./test.sh: line 30: syntax error near unexpected token ('   
./test.sh: line 30:     paste <(printf "%s\n" "TOP")
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How **exactly** are you running it? what '#!' line (if any) starts your script? It looks like you are invoking a shell interpreter that doesn't support that syntax (e.g. `dash` instead of `bash`).

Comment: I have `#!/bin/sh` at the top. I executed as `bash test.sh` but it did not work either.

Comment: `bash` in POSIX mode doesn't support that syntax either (when called with `--posix` or as `/bin/sh`). Use `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @NecNecco: Do you have `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable set when you start `bash`?

Comment: @jordanm switching to `#!/bin/bash` at the top fixed the problem.

Comment: @Gnouc I just run `bash test.sh`. How can I set or get `POSIXLY_CORRECT`?

Comment: @NecNecco: Try `bash -c 'echo $POSIXLY_CORRECT'` to check if it is set.

Comment: @NecNecco: You can check in any startup file that run `set -o posix`. Or maybe your `bash` is compiled with `--enable-strict-posix-default`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) is not specified by POSIX, so not all POSIX shells support it, only some shells like `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh88`, `ksh93`.

In CentOS system, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`. When `bash` is invoked with name `sh`, `bash` enters posix mode ([Bash Startup Files - Invoked with name sh](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)). In bash versions prior to 5.1, *process substitution* support was disabled when invoked in posix mode, causing a syntax error.

The script should work if you call `bash` directly: `bash test.sh`. If not, maybe `bash` has entered posix mode. This can occur if you start `bash` with the `--posix` argument or if the variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set when `bash` starts:

```
$ bash --posix test.sh 
test.sh: line 54: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 54: `paste <(printf "%s\n" "TOP")'

$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 bash test.sh 
test.sh: line 54: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 54: `paste <(printf "%s\n" "TOP")
```

Or `bash` is built with `--enable-strict-posix-default` option.

Here, you don't need process substitution, you can use standard shell pipes:

```
printf "%s\n" "TOP" | paste -
```

`-` is the standard way to tell `paste` to read the data from stdin. With some `paste` implementations, you can omit it though that's not standard.

Where it would be useful is when pasting the output of more than one command like in:

```
paste <(cmd1) <(cmd2)
```

On systems that support `/dev/fd/n`, that can be done in `sh` with:

```
{ cmd1 4<&- | { cmd2 3<&- | paste /dev/fd/3 -; } 3<&0 <&4 4<&-; } 4<&0
```

(it's what `<(...)` does internally).

Answer (score 4):

Here's another workaround. Instead of running the command, run bash and pass the command to bash using -c:

```
bash -c 'paste <(printf "%s\n" "TOP")'
```